# Plutus script execution at every end of epoch

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, script, script-addresses

I would like to develop a Plutus script that executes each time an epoch ends.

What's the best way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Jey earlier, blockchains and smart contracts remain latent until triggered by a user submitted transaction.

One way you could pull this off is that you could use the cardano-cli application to create, sign and submit a transaction which executed the plutus script at the end of every epoch. You can find out more about [cardano-cli and plutus scripts here](https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/Plutus-transactions) and a simple sample [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/main/Alonzo-solutions/exercise3/e3SampleSolution.md)

UPDATE: I realized that I missed out explaining how this could be done by creating an javascript bot which submits this kind of transaction near the end of the epoch automatically.
You can use the [cardanocli-js](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/cardanocli-js) javascript library to achieve this... here's a [basic sample](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardanocli-js/), but you can pretty much do any kind of action that the cardano-cli can do, in a programmatic submission.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I learned at the Plutus Pioneer Program but I just needed to be sure I was understanding it correctly. Thank you very much for your clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Scripts are executed as part of a transaction validation. That means: no transaction -> no script execution. The blockchain has no mechanism of timed or automatic script execution. What you can do is to implement transaction submission at every new epoch in your off-chain code.